# How to make a dotted (unordered) list in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I make a dotted list in Jetpack Compose in the simplest way possible?

Here is an example of what I mean:

[image: Dotted list example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
val itemsList = (0..5).toList() //just an example

Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
    itemsList.forEach() {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 8.dp)
                    .size(8.dp)
                    .background(Color.Black, shape = CircleShape),
            )

            Text("Text Text $it")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add order list using string resource? Any feedback would be much appreciated.